# Why was the Rebel base on Crait abandoned?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In TLJ, the remnants of the Resistance fleet head for what Leia says is an abandoned Rebel base on Crait.

*Why was the rebel base on Crait abandoned?*

- Had it been discovered by the Empire?
- Was it too small, too remote, or too inhospitable to be worth keeping?
- Did the Rebels regularly abandon bases as a security measure, sort of like changing your password every six months? Considering that the Rebel base on Dantooine had apparently been abandoned for some time before its discovery by the Empire (in ANH), it seems plausible that regular base rotation is a standard Rebel practice, but it seems awfully expensive.

Comment: Because at that point the Empire was defeated and the Republic was back in control. Rebel bases were no longer necessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) indicates that during the Rebellion Era the base's security was compromised, hence their decision to abandon it.

> **BASE DEFENCES**
>
> The Rebellion hastily abandoned Crait during the base's construction when a traitorous ally alerted an elite Imperial unit, SCAR Squadron, to their location. The rebels left behind their Spiezoc v-120 and v-232 artillery emplacements.

Since Crait had no discernible value, Leia anticipates (correctly) that that planet isn't likely to appear on the First Order's star charts.

Comment: And the place is covered in salt. You think *sand* gets everywhere....

Comment: @Irishpanda - Washing salt crystals out of your (ahem) areas is a piece of cake compared to getting rid of sand.

Comment: But considerably more uncomfortable in the interim.

Comment: @Irishpanda - It depends where the salt is. Around the rim of a margarita is fine by me.

Comment: Th-this margarita has salt. I distinctly asked for no salt....*mutters* set the rebel base on fire...